# Nant merge task not executing

Tags: .net, cruisecontrol.net, nant

I have a Nant merge task aimed at a nunit test output.xml  I have installed the relevant xsl transform files and the menu option does show up to see the NUnit details. But all the counters are zero, and inspecting the xml log file for the build I can see that the output has not been merged.

Does any one have any idea why this would be?

dashboard.config contains

```
<buildPlugins>
      <buildReportBuildPlugin>
        <xslFileNames>
          <xslFile>xsl\header.xsl</xslFile>
          <xslFile>xsl\modifications.xsl</xslFile>
        </xslFileNames>
      </buildReportBuildPlugin>
      <buildLogBuildPlugin />
      <xslReportBuildPlugin description="NUnit Details" actionName="NUnitDetailsBuildReport" xslFileName="xsl\tests.xsl" />
      <xslReportBuildPlugin description="NUnit Timings" actionName="NUnitTimingsBuildReport" xslFileName="xsl\timing.xsl" />
      <xslReportBuildPlugin description="NAnt Output" actionName="NAntOutputBuildReport" xslFileName="xsl\Nant.xsl" />
      <xslReportBuildPlugin description="NAnt Timings" actionName="NAntTimingsBuildReport" xslFileName="xsl\NantTiming.xsl" />
    </buildPlugins>
```

This is inside the ccnet.config

```
<publishers>
  <merge>
     <files>
         <file>D:\XmlOutput\nunit-results.xml</file>
     </files>
  </merge>
  <xmllogger>
    <logDir>c:\logs\Trunk</logDir>
  </xmllogger>
</publishers>
```

TIA

Andrew

**UPDATE 1**

The merge only works if all the tests pass.  So my trouble is that I need to merge the report even if the tests fail. TIA Andrew

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear that my other projects had the merge task underneathe the xmllogger tag.  I can now confirm that this is order dependant and you need the merge tasks to come before this xml logger attorbute.

Cheers,

Andrew